# Обновление в ListView, после изменения записи

Tags: java, gui, javafx

У меня есть часть приложения, которая содержит ListView со списком пользователей (класс User), которые, пока, при запуске приложения добавляются в

`ObservableList<User> users = new FXCollections.observableArrayList();`

В классе контроллере, в методе initialize(), инициализирую отображение имени в ListView:

```
    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        nameList.setCellFactory((ListView<User> userListView) -> new UsersFormatCell());
    }
```

Код класса UsersFormatCell:

```
    public class UsersFormatCell extends ListCell<User> {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(User user, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(user, empty);

            // format of the cell in list

            setText(user == null ? "" : user.getName());
        }
    }
```

В классе User, имеются все необходимые get'теры и set'теры.
Над данным списком пользователей, когда из UI, провожу операции удаления записи, или добавление новой, то список в UI автоматически обновлется. Но когда я изменяю запись в UI, то список не обновляется, хотя в ObervableList запись обновляется.

Подскажите пожалуйста, **ЧЯДНТ**?

Comment: Что значит "когда я изменяю запись в UI" ? Ты тыкаешь на строчку 2 раза, у тебя появляется TextField, куда ты заносишь новые данные? Или что?

Comment: Выделяю запись в ListView, нажимаю н кнопку "Edit", открываю диалог редактирования объекта, редактирую поля, если жму "Ок", то изменения сохраняются в ObservableList и закрывается диалог, если Cancel - то ничего не изменяется и диалог закрывается.

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы все сработало, необходимо сделать следующее

В классе `UsersFormatCell` переопределить метод : `startEdit()`.

Далее необходимо написать в `startEdit()` вызвать для начала `super.startEdit()`, далее описать форму, в которой будет происходит изменение.

Затем, если будет нажата кнопка OK, то необходимо у данного объекта класса  `UsersFormatCell` вызвать метод `commitEdit(newUser)`, и после этого, значение запишется в ячейку.

Если нажата кнопка Cancel, то необходимо вызвать метод `cancelEdit()`

**Примерный код**

```
public class UsersFormatCell extends ListCell<User> {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(User user, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(user, empty);

            // format of the cell in list

            setText(user == null ? "" : user.getName());
        }

    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        super.startEdit();
        User user = getItem(); // получаем текущего юзера
        if (user != null) {
            TextField field = new TextField(user.getName()); // мы будем менять имя
            Button btnOk = new Button("OK");
            btnOk.setOnAction(event -> {
                user.setName(textField.getText())
                commitEdit(user);
            );
            Button btnCancel = new Button("Cancel");
            btnCancel.setOnAction(event -> cancelEdit());
            BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
            pane.setRight(btnOk);
            pane.setLeft(btnCancel);
            pane.setCenter(field);
            Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 500, 500);
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setScene(scene);
        }

    }

    }
```

Соответственно при нажатии кнопки `Edit` у тебя должен вызываться метод `startEdit()`

Comment: Объясни, пожалуйста, как из контроллера, где в методе `initialize()` был проинициализирован ListView, описать вызов `startEdit()` в методе `@FXML private void handleEdit()`?

Comment: Реализуй логику в методе listView.setOnEditStart(сюда логику)